# Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of independent events. Show that, for every $x$, the event $$A=\left\{\omega:\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n I_{A_k}(\omega) \rightarrow x\right\}$$ has probability either $0$ or $1$.

I think if I show this event as a tail event then the event has probability $0$ or $1$ by Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law. Any Help?

Comment: Who are $I_k$? And who is $n$? Did you mean to take the limit there?

Comment: sorry. I have edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event under consideration is independent from any finite number of $A_n$. The sum converges if its tail converges, so to measure it, you need to know the tail behavior of the $A_n$'s. The event $A$ is determined by the sequence $\{A_1,A_2, \dots\}$ but not by a finite set of the form $\{A_1,A_2, \ldots A_m\}$. Hence it belongs to the tail $σ-$ algebra.

---

This is the basic idea, which you can formulate as follows. Let $$σ(A_m, A_{m+1}, \ldots)$$ be the $σ-$ algebra generated by all events $A_k$ with $k\ge m$. The tail $σ-$ algebra $\mathcal T$ is defined as $$\mathcal T:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty}σ(A_m, A_{m+1}, \ldots)$$ Now, the event $A:=\left\{\omega:\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n I_{A_k}(\omega) \rightarrow x\right\}$, for any $m>0$ depends only on the events $A_k$ with $k\ge m$ (see an explanation below) and hence it belongs to $σ(A_m, A_{m+1},\ldots)$ for *every* $m\ge 1$ (we can remove the first $m$ terms and the tail behavior remains unchanged). Hence $A$ belongs to the intersection of these $σ-$ algebras which is by the definition the tail $σ-$ algebra $\mathcal T$.

By the Kolmogorov $0-1$ law, every event in $T$ has probability either $0$ or $1$ (although it is usually hard to say which).

---

To see why $A$ depends only on the events $A_k$ for $k\ge m$, fix $m<n$ and write: $$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^nI_{A_k}(ω)=\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^mI_{A_k}(ω)+\frac1n \sum_{k=m+1}^nI_{A_k}(ω)$$ Letting $n \to +\infty$ this gives \begin{align}\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^nI_{A_k}(ω)&=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{m}I_{A_k}(ω)+\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=m+1}^nI_{A_k}(ω)\\[0.2cm]&=0+\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=m+1}^nI_{A_k}(ω)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}I_{A_{m+k}(ω)}\end{align} This shows that the limit does not depend on the first $m$ events and since $m$ was arbitrary (but fixed) this shows the assertion.

Comment: "To measure it, you need to know infinitely many of the $A_n$'s" I fail to get this part of the argument. Care to explain?

Comment: "Now,the event $A:=$ ... lies certainly in $σ(A_n, A_{n+1},\ldots)$ for *every* $n\ge 1$, because it depends on infinitely many $A_n$'s." Now this argument seems squarely wrong: lots of events depending on infinitely many $A_n$s are *not* in the tail sigma-algebra.

Comment: @Did I think that I nailed it! What do you think?

Comment: Closer  now, but it remains to explain more precisely why "the event $A:=\left\{\omega:\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n I_{A_k}(\omega) \rightarrow x\right\}$, for any $n>0$ depends only on the events $A_k$ with $k\ge n$".

Comment: @Did This is it.

Comment: I don't see how you can directly say that $A$ belongs to $\sigma(A_m,A_{m+1},\dots)$, this seems like a big jump. Also shouldn't it be $m=1$ in the definition of the tail-field?

Answer (score 1):

$\{I_{A_n}\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables. Consequently, you can apply the following argument, which is true for every sequence of independent r.v.'s $\{X_n\}$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{ḱ=1}^n X_n$ and let $0 < b_n \uparrow +\infty$. Then, $\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n}$ and $\liminf \frac{S_n}{b_n}$ are tail functions, see definition 1 and proposition 2. Thus:

$$ \{ \omega \in \Omega: \frac{S_n(\omega)}{b_n} \rightarrow x \} = \left(\liminf \frac{S_n}{b_n}\right)^{-1}\{x\} \bigcap \left(\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n}\right)^{-1}\{x\} $$

What implies that $\{ \omega \in \Omega: \frac{S_n(\omega)}{b_n} \rightarrow x \}$ is a tail event.

**Definition 1.** Tail functions are random variables measurable for the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

**Proposition 2.** $\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n}$ and $\liminf \frac{S_n}{b_n}$ are tail functions.

**Proof.**

It is just presented the proof for the limit superior since the other one works similarly.

In order to proof the assertion it is enough proving  that $\left[\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n} > a\right]$ is a tail event for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The statement is achieved using the following analysis argument, which needs that $b_n \uparrow \infty$:

**Lemma.** Let $x_n$ be an arbitrary sequence, $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ and $0 < b_n \uparrow +\infty$. For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$ \limsup \frac{s_n}{b_n} > a \iff \limsup \frac{s_{n+m}-s_m}{b_{n+m}} > a $$

**Proof.**

Use that $\frac{s_m}{b_n} \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. If you need more insight in the proof, then tell me. I don't want to fulfill the answer with analysis details. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Thus, we have

$$ \left[ \limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n} > a \right] = \left[ \limsup \frac{S_{n+m}- S_m}{b_{n+m}} > a \right] \in \beta(X_m, X_{m+1}, \ldots) \ \forall \ m \in \mathbb{N} $$

since $\frac{S_{n+m}- S_m}{b_{n+m}}$ is measurable in $\beta(X_m, X_{m+1}, \ldots)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and, thus, so it is its limit superior.

Finally, the event is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra because this one is the intersection of every $\beta(X_m, X_{m+1}, \ldots)$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: "Then ... are tail functions" This is of course *what needs to be proven*.

Comment: Added that proof @Did. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I don't understand why someone put a -1 :(